# Finding an average on Google Sheets based on another column's name

Tags: variables, google-sheets, average, conditional-operator

I'm currently working on Google Sheets and was wondering how I could query an average for one numerical column based on the conditional naming of a qualitative column. In this example, I'm trying to create list of average 'Stars' based on name of 'Country'.

Here is a screenshot of the sheets for reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0imCZ.png)

Tried running some calculations manually through AVERAGE() but wasn't sure how I could utilize potentially an AVERAGEIF() function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything in I3 downwards and K3 downwards, then enter the following in I3:

```
=query({E2:F},"select Col1,'',avg(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1",0)
```